# Spring boot fails to start with HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hsqldb

I am trying to create a simple spring boot app which would connect to HSQLDB and work with User table, however I am getting this when trying to start it.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

With the whole console output here:
http://pastebin.com/7HminjFL

My files ares:

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "hello")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "hello")
@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Account.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User", schema = "PUBLIC")
public class Account implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "Login", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "Password", nullable = false)
    private String password;


    protected Account() {
        // no-args constructor required by JPA spec
        // this one is protected since it shouldn't be used directly
    }

    public Account(String login, String password) {
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
        return;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return;
    }
}
```

AccountRepository.java

```
public interface AccountRepository extends JpaRepository<Account, Long> {

    Long countByLogin(String login);
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:hsqldb:file:C:\DB\TestDB
spring.datasource.username=SA
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
```

Comment: You are using Spring Boot then use Spring boot you are trying very hard not to. Move your `Application` class to the `hello` package, remove all annotations but the `SpringBootApplication` annotation. Then start the application again, if it still fails, add the stack trace to your question.

Comment: I have removed the annotations (which I've only added while trying to resolve this issue) and the same error still persist, I've pasted the whole console output to pastebin since it is huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your stack trace gives some direction to the problem.

> Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: hello.Account

Switch your `@Id` annotation import on `Account` class.

Probably you are using: import `org.springframework.data.annotation.Id`. Exchange for `import javax.persistence.Id` and try to start your application again;

---

By the way, `@SpringBootApplication` is a convenient way to start your SpringBoot application. If you use it, you don't need to add `@Configuration`, @EnableAutoConfiguration and `@ComponentScan`.

> @SpringBootApplication
>
> Indicates a {@link Configuration configuration} class that declares one or more
>   {@link Bean @Bean} methods and also triggers {@link EnableAutoConfiguration
>    auto-configuration} and {@link ComponentScan component scanning}.
>
> This is a  convenience
>    annotation that is equivalent to declaring {@code @Configuration},
>    {@code @EnableAutoConfiguration} and {@code @ComponentScan}.